# Postgres: DB information for logging purpose

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am migrating from Oracle to Postgres and in oracle we are logging some DB information and looking for the corresponding syntax in Postgres.

The Oracle query is

```
SELECT sid, serial#, username, machine, osuser 
FROM v$session 
where sid=SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','SID')
```

I can find the pid and the username in postgres:

1. I think I don't need the serial# in Postgres as pid can uniquely identify the session
2. How to find the machine and osuser in Postgres

Note: I am using Postgres 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest is the following:

```
select pid, usename, client_addr, client_hostname
from pg_stat_activity
where pid = pg_backend_pid();
```

`client_hostname` will only contain a valid hostname if [`log_hostname`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOGGING-WHAT) is enabled.

There is no equivalent for `osuser` as Postgres does not send this information to the server when connecting (and it's a bad idea to rely on that in Oracle as it can be changed to whatever the client application likes).

Answer (score 1):

You can query [the `pg_stat_activity` view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-ACTIVITY-VIEW). From the documentation:

> The pg_stat_activity view will have one row per server process, showing information related to the current activity of that process.

Interesting columns include:

- `pid`: process ID of this backend
- `usename`: Name of the user logged into this backend
- `client_hostname`: Host name of the connected client (when log_hostname is enabled)
- `client_addr`: IP address of the client connecte

As far as concerns you cannot determine the client's machine in Postgres (see [this thread](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/1d581afe0411051153dce7837@mail.gmail.com) for your reference)